# Displaying into ListView issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, listview, jquery-mobile

I am trying to add search functionality into jquery mobile and i got success in adding and its working fine .Now the issue that i got as a result of this is in Displaying .Now my contact list is getting displayed as paragraph type with underline in each contact whereas on clicking the search button and after searching the lists gets refreshed to listview and that is what i want to display at before also..

Here is the fiddle demo..[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/et2nLwfb/30/)

And here is the HTML..

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-inset="true" data-input="#autocomplete-input" id="ContactList">       
</ul>
```

Please help me to resolve this..
Thanks..

Refrence files.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile.structure-1.0.1.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.css" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/launch_icon_57.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="images/launch_icon_72.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="images/launch_icon_114.png" />
<script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/function.js"></script>
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the following CSS will get rid of the underlines for you:

```
ul[data-role=listview] a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

All that's doing is telling the page to remove the underline from anchor links in your listviews.

Hope that helps.

---

**Update**

I understand the problem now.  Okay, so you're just missing some of the classes that are being applied by jQuery Mobile.

If you change this line of your JavaScript, it'll appear how you expect it to:

```
$('#ContactList').append('<li><a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-carat-r"><h3 class="ui-li-heading">' + name + '</h3><div class="ui-li-desc">Club ' + phone + '</div></a></li>');
```

The important part being that we're adding `class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-carat-r"` to your `<a href="#">` element that you're injecting in the DOM via JavaScript.

**[Fiddle with the proper display here](http://jsfiddle.net/et2nLwfb/61/)**

That should fix it.

Comment: This removed the underline but did not solved my issue.Will you please click search button and search from the list ..The kind of View/display i get that time i need the same in start also.

Comment: Its not working in my mobile device ...Its Ok in fiddle .But as soon as i saw it on mobile its not the same..so its not working

Comment: I think this is because of jquery mobile css version issue..Please see my post to see the versions that i am using

Comment: It is, but the fiddle only allows using jQuery mobile down to 1.1.1.  Yours is very out-of-date.  I'd recommend updating it.